# How to remove the message "vim-minimap" [New File]" after vim-minimap intallation?

Tags: vim, macvim, vundle

I installed `vim-minimap` with `Vundle` adding this line to my `~/.vimrc`

```
Plugin 'severin-lemaignan/vim-minimap'
```

and I added `Minimap` in my `~/.gvimrc`

Now everytime I launch a `gvim` from the terminal, with or without arguments, I get the message `"vim-minimap" [New File]` in the terminal.

How can I avoid having this message?

Comment: Just so I understand: you're starting gVim from a terminal, and when you do it prints that message to the terminal before it starts? Does this happen regardless of whether you open gVim with file arguments? What is your `$TERM`?

Comment: The message appears before gvim starts in both cases with and without file arguments. `TERM=xterm-256color`

Comment: removing `Minimap` from `~/.gvimrc` solves the issue for now